# Imce file browser not showing select button

Tags: media, files

The IMCE file browser seems to be missing it's select button. On this File field, I'd like content creators to choose an image that is already located on the server (not uploading a new image).

What setting might I have missed?

[image]

**The field on this content type is configured as follows:**

[image]

**The profile is configured as followed:**

[image]

**File Permissions**
The /tmp folder is owned by the apache user and is chmod'ed to 2775. The /sites/default/files/images folder is owned by apache and chmod'ed to 755.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh for heavens sake. I turned *off* Aggregate-JavaScript and cleared cache. The select button shows up. As to why this happened I can't say. I'm leaving this answer here in case any one comes up against this.

Temporarily turn off magnification and clear cache.

Comment: Thank you for this! I think this also solved another issue with batching (like rebuilding permission) for me as well.