# Imce file/image browser not showing any buttons tab

Tags: 7, files

I am using imce as image browser. I installed imce for filefield module to select files from imce repository and i have given all permissions as in below image
[image]

When it will go to imce repository those buttons are not showing, see the below image
[image]
I followed [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/139439/imce-file-browser-not-showing-select-button) link but that is not working for me.
Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the "administrative" theme - I observed this behavior with a custom theme, but it rendered the buttons if I changed themes to one of the standard themes.